# graphQL with Sequelize and Mysql duplicate field in relation

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, graphql, relationship

https://www.graphqlbin.com/v2/gLg9FP

I am stuck with this problem for a day now and need somebody help.
I have 2 sequelize models

```
      module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
            const Periodo = sequelize.define('periodo', {
...
                    cod_casa: {
                        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                        allowNull: false,
                        field: 'cod_casa'
                    },
                   ....
                },
     ...
            );

            Periodo.associate = (models) => {
                Periodo.belongsTo(models.casa);
            };

            return Periodo;
        }
```

and

```
  const Casa = sequelize.define('casa', {
                cod_casa: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                    allowNull: false,
                    primaryKey: true,
                    autoIncrement: true,
                    field: 'cod_casa'
                },

.....
    Casa.associate = (models) => {
        Casa.hasMany(models.periodo);
    };

    return Casa;
}
```

But graphQl always return an error :

"extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
          "parent": {
            "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
            "errno": 1054,
            "sqlState": "42S22",
            "sqlMessage": "Unknown column 'casaCodCasa' in 'field list'",
            "sql": "SELECT `id`, `cod_casa`, `inicio`, `fim`, `preco_semana` AS `precoSemana`, `preco_dia` AS `precoDia`, `preco_fimsemana` AS `precoFimsemana`, `estadia_minima` AS `estadiaMinima`, `descricao`, `observacoes`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, **casaCodCasa** FROM `periodo` AS `periodo` WHERE **periodo`.`casaCodCasa** = 23;"
          },

The problem seems to be in relation definition. 
I also have the resolvers and graphQL schema well defined.
Anybody been trougth someting like this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define foreign key custom as you are not using default primary key as id

```
Periodo.belongsTo(models.casa,{foreignKey: 'cod_casa'}); // <--- HERE
```

As per the [**DOC**](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html) :

```
const User = this.sequelize.define('user', {/* attributes */})
const Company  = this.sequelize.define('company', {/* attributes */});

User.belongsTo(Company); // Will add companyId to user

const User = this.sequelize.define('user', {/* attributes */}, {underscored: true})
const Company  = this.sequelize.define('company', {
  uuid: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    primaryKey: true
  }
});

User.belongsTo(Company); // <----- Will add company_uuid to user
```

> **NOTE : User.belongsTo(Company); // <----- Will add company_uuid to user , so in your case its casaCodCasa**

Comment: I am using primary key    const Periodo = sequelize.define('periodo', {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
                field: 'id'
            },
            cod_casa: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                allowNull: false,
                field: 'cod_casa'
            },

Comment: Yes but not in casa table, that's why just change the line as I have suggested and run your code.

Comment: i ve changed the line ... no effect at all. Maybe problem is because primary key of Casa have same name foreign key of Periodo?

Comment: cannot share localhost

Comment: if i use query {
    periodos {
         casaid
  }
}

Comment: get same eroor with field

Answer (score 0):

Fix consists of o custom foreign key option in both definition of the relation /association 
ex:

```
Periodo.associate = (models) => {
        Periodo.belongsTo(models.casa,**{foreignKey: 'cod_casa'}**);
    };
```

and

```
Casa.associate = (models) => {
        Casa.hasMany(models.periodo,**{ foreignKey: 'cod_casa' }**);
        Casa.hasMany(models.feedback,{ foreignKey: 'cod_casa' });
    };
```

as @Vivek Doshi saind but for both models.